# Math.round and Math.ceil not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to round the users input but I can seem to get my double to round to an int. Basically, when I enter 4.4999 it wont round up to 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: y := f(x) ...

f doesn't "change" x ...

Comment: `Math.round()` works similar to `Math.floor(a + 0.5d)`. If you calculate: `4.4999 + 0.5` that will not give you more than `5` and that's why you will not get `5` with round in your instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Math.ceil()` *returns* the ceiled value. It can't change the value of the variable it takes as argument, because Java passes arguments by value. So you need to do

```
hours = Math.ceil(hours);
```

Comment: (int)Math.ceil(3/2.0) will give answer 2   

(int)Math.ceil(3/2) will give answer 1

In order to get the float value, you need to cast (or add .0) to one of the arguments

Answer (score 9):

The actual solution is to use double inside the `ceil` method.

`Math.ceil(7 * 50 / 100)` will return `3.0` even though the actual value resulting from `7*50/100` is `3.5`. It is because since everything is `int`, the result of `350/100` itself will be `3`.

If however, if you give `Math.ceil(7 * 50 / 100D)`, the result would be `4.0`.

So, the `4.999` in your question should be a `double` and not a result of an integer operation like `4999/1000`.

Just make sure that whatever you give inside a the `ceil` is `double` and not an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Both function return the rounded (or ceiled) values, but don't change the variable passed as parameter.

Use eg. `hours = Math.ceil(hours);`.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.ciel` returns a `Double`. Something like this should work (inside of your `hours > 0` block):

```
cost += Math.ceil(hours) * hourlyRate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the result of `Math.ceil(hours)` back to `hours` so it will never round.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 15

int b = 2;

int x = (int) Math.ceil( a / b );

int y = (int) Math.ceil( (double) a / (double) b );
```

**Results**:

x: 7

y: 8

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.